# Dynamic infowindow array from database cat get to work. included show/hide different marker type and marker cluster in one

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Im trying go get my map to work for over a month now. I have read many many posts but cant get it to work 100%. I tried all kind of suggentions from here. 
So far cluster marker works, show/hide marker type works. 
Problem is that I can't get dynamic infowindow for each marker using loop.
So far I can get data if I use locations[i][0] for name etc.
Main problem is that I need to have link to detail page in info window. Without that ability this map have no purpose. If someone could give some advice or solution it would be awsome.

contentInfoWindow brakes the infowindow when I use in infowindow.setContent.
infowindow.setContent works only when used like this `infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);` to show name. I could add more locations arrays but it is not what I need.

here is the full code.

```
function getHtmlInfoWindow($item)
    {
    if($item->imagename!=NULL){ $img=$item->imagename->name;}else{$img='noimage.jpg';}
   $myHtml='';
   $myHtml .='<div id="propertydetail"><div class="title">';
   $myHtml .='<a target="_parent" href="'. $item->link.'" title="'.str_replace('"',' ',$item->name).'">'.$item->name.'</a></div>';
   $myHtml .='<div class="image"><img src="images/properties/images/thumbs/'.$item->id.'/'.$img.'" alt="'.str_replace('"',' ',$item->name).'" width="100" height="75"></div>';
   $myHtml .='<div class="text">';
    if ($item->name_type) {
      $myHtml .=JText::_($item->name_type).'<br />';
   }
   if ($item->name_category) {
      $myHtml .=JText::_($item->name_category).'<br />';
   }
   if ($item->name_locality) {
      $myHtml .=JText::_($item->name_locality).'<br />';
   }
   if ($item->address) {
      $myHtml .=JText::_($item->address).'<br />';
   }
   $myHtml .='</div>';
   $myHtml .='<div class="property_button">';
   $myHtmlimg ='<a target="_parent" class="BottomlnkDetail" href="'.$item->link.'" title="'.$item->id.'">'.JText::_('MOD_PROP_MAP_VIEW_DETAILS').'</a>';
   //$myHtml .='<button type="button" id="sbox-btn-close" onclick="window.parent.document.getElementById(\\\'sbox-window\\\').close();window.close();">Cancelar</button>';
   $myHtml .='</div>';
   $myHtml .='</div>';
    return $myHtml;
    }

   $useTranslations=$cParams->get('useTranslations','0');
   if($useTranslations)
    {
      $lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();
      $thisLang = $lang->getTag();
    }else{
      $thisLang  = NULL;
    }
   $item=$list[0];
   $MapDistance=$params->get('MapDistance',14);
   $lat = $item->lat;
   $lng = $item->lng;
?>



 <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<fieldset id="form">
   <p>
    <input class="checkbox" id="1" name="1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" />
    <label for="1"><?php echo JText::_('APARTMENT');?></label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input class="checkbox" id="2" name="2" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="2" />
    <label for="2"><?php echo JText::_('ROOM');?></label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input class="checkbox" id="3" name="3" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="3" />
    <label for="3"><?php echo JText::_('HOUSE');?></label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input class="checkbox" id="4" name="4" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="4" />
    <label for="4"><?php echo JText::_('HOTEL');?></label>
    </p>

</fieldset>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=<?php echo $thisLang;?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="modules/mod_prop_map/tmpl/markerclusterer.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    var contentInfoWindow=new Array();
    <?php
        for($x=0;$x<count($list);$x++)
            {
            echo "\n"."contentInfoWindow[".$x."]='".getHtmlInfoWindow($list[$x])."';"."\n";
            }
        ?>



 var markers = new Array();
    var locations = [
     <?php
        for($x=0;$x<count($list);$x++)
            {
            $product = $list[$x];
            echo "['".$product->name."',".$product->type.",".$product->lat.",".$product->lng.",".$x."],"."\n";
            }
        ?>
    ];



var mcOptions =
    {
        gridSize: 50//, maxZoom: 6
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: <?php echo $MapDistance;?>,
          scrollwheel: true,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat;?>, <?php echo $lng;?>),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


var markerCluster = null;   // Initializes markerCluster
    var markers = []; 
    var marker, i;

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
        map: map,
        icon: '<?php echo JURI::base()?>components/com_properties/includes/img/map_'+locations[i][1]+'_marker.png'

      });


        markers.push(marker);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());    





var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) { return function() {


infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
          //zIndex: locations[i][1]
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);


    // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
      function show(type) {
        for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {
          if (locations[i][1] == type) {
            markers[i].setVisible(true);
          }
        }
      }

      // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
      function hide(type) {
        for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {
          if (locations[i][1] == type) {
            markers[i].setVisible(false);
          }
        }
      }



         (function($){

      // == show or hide the categories initially ==


        $(".checkbox").click(function(){
            var types = $(this).attr("value");

            // If checked
            if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                show(types);
            }
            else
            {
                hide(types);
            }
          });
         })(jQuery);

</script>
```